# What exactly is this java code doing?

Tags: java, string, file-io

I'm trying to write a program that requires I read text from a file. In doing research, I found this code that does exactly what I need it to do:

```
String string="";

try{

        InputStream ips = new FileInputStream("WORDS.txt"); 
        InputStreamReader ipsr = new InputStreamReader(ips);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ipsr);
        String line;
        while ((line=br.readLine())!=null){
            System.out.println(line);
            string+=line+"\n";
        }
        br.close(); 
    }       
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
```

Can someone please explain how this code is working? I am new to programming, and I am not familiar with most of this code. It is not for homework--it is a program I am writing for my own personal gain. Thank you.

Comment: What happened when you tried running it?

Comment: How do you know this code does exactly what you need to do if you don't know what it does?

Comment: When I run it, it prints out line by line, the contents of the text file, which is exactly what I need for this program. I don't understand how it works though.

Comment: @user2184665 start reading the class-and method-level JavaDocs for every class and method you "don't understand" in this piece of code. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api

Comment: It is accomplishing what I need, which is to print out the contents of the text file. I guess I'm looking for a breakdown of how it is accomplishing that.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for tips on how to ask questions here.  Your question as it stands does not fit the requirements.  You should be asking your teacher this type of question, and/or doing the required studying on your own.

Comment: Step through the code in a debugger. Step into methods you don't understand. Read the Javadocs. Nothing will help you learn faster than real, on-hands experimentation.

Comment: Thank you. I have never posted here before, and I apologize if I have offended anyone by not following the proper protocol/guidelines.

Comment: @user2184665 sorry to be a damp rag but this sort of question isn't a good fit for [SO]. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79133/133242

Answer (score 5):

After you have understood what the program does (which is important, those are essential concepts for any Java programmer, hopefully someone will fill in), here is what I would do to improve it:

- Don't have code for this at all. The problem of reading files into Strings has been solved already. Use [Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io//javadocs/api-2.4/index.html).
- Do not use String concatenation in a loop. Use StringBuilder. Initialize the StringBuilder with your best guess for its required capacity (such as the file size).
- Specify an explicit character set when creating the Reader. Otherwise your program will not be portable across different computers.
- Do not first remove line breaks and then add them again, unless this is really what you want. This potentially changes the data being read (if the original file used a different line break scheme).
- Do not catch the Exception and print it. Let it propagate up the call stack to a piece of code that can deal with it.
- Do not initialize the result String to empty. If the code completes, the String will hold your data, if not, you want null or an exception. The empty String will just make it harder to find errors. Best not to initialize the String at all, not even to null. Then you would get a nice compile error here, asking you to explicitly specify what the String should be in case of the exception.
- Put the code that reads from the file in its own method. Have it return a String. What you do with that String later is of no concern to this method.

Comment: This is helpful advice.  I'd also add that you can search each class in Google and will find a type of page called a JavaDoc (usually in docs.oracle.com) that describes each one in detail.  Go over them one at a time, and do so until you understand each one.  You'll learn very fast from an authoritative source.

Comment: +1 on @phatfingers advice on using Google to find Javadoc. That's what I do, too, even though any proper IDE will have Javadoc bundled and able to display it when you mouse over methods and such. The documentation for the JDK is very good. Find a convenient way to read it.

Answer (score 1):

At a high level, it reads a file line-by-line, and builds up a string*  consisting of the character data from the file.

---

<sub>*in an unnecessarily inefficient manner; string concatenation in a loop should almost always be replaced with usage of a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).</sub>